# How to shuffle TextView elements within GridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-studio

I am trying to make a shuffle button which will randomly reorder the TextView items (simply letters) within my GridView. I've attempted to simply make a copy of the list of elements, `Collections.shuffle()` it, then loop through the actual elements in the GridView and apply the new characteristics to them. However, when I do this, after two or three presses all the letters and characteristcs are the same.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        private static final String[] LETTERSET = generateLetterset.main();
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lettersGrid);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.letter_text_view_item, LETTERSET);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


 public void Shuffle(View v) {
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lettersGrid);
        List<TextView>letterList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < gridView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TextView letter = (TextView) gridView.getChildAt(i);
            letterList.add(letter);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(letterList);


        for (int i = 0; i < gridView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TextView currentLetter = (TextView) gridView.getChildAt(i);
            TextView newLetter = letterList.get(i);

            String txt = newLetter.getText().toString();
            boolean selected = newLetter.isClickable();
            int color = newLetter.getCurrentTextColor();

            currentLetter.setText(txt);
            currentLetter.setClickable(selected);
            currentLetter.setTextColor(color);
        }
    }
```

Comment: as in any other AdapterView ... shuffle adapter's underlaying data and notify adapterview about changes

Comment: After your first for loop, you completely delete all the GridView elements, and then shuffle the list and then add them into GridView again, you can try it.

Comment: Selvin, could you elaborate a bit on the implementation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes.
* declare adapter object outside oncreate

```
    private static final String[] LETTERSET = generateLetterset.main();
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> stringList;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lettersGrid);

        stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(LETTERSET ));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.letter_text_view_item, stringList );
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And update Shuffle function as below

```
public void Shuffle(View v) { 
    Collections.shuffle(stringList); 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: In my current code I actually use this, my trouble is where and how to implement it with the GridView

Comment: Yes, oddly what happens is with each shuffle the list will become more homogeneous. For example, if the list is [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]  it will become something like [f, c, c, a, c, a, b] then [a, b, c, c, c, c ], then [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, ]

Comment: could you post the code where initially set data to your gridview

Comment: updated my answer.i hope this will solve your problem. notifyDataSetChanged()  refreshes the view if the data has been changed.

Comment: This feels close but it doesn't work. I think notifyDataSetChanged() does not work because letterList() is not part of the adapter, only a new List created which mirrors data in the adapter

Comment: change letterList to LETTERSET

Comment: That doesn't work either because each textview within the gridview has multiple properties beside their letter...some are red, some green, some clickable, some not, etc depending on user input. If I only chage the textview's letters, then this will not implement the shuffle behavior I need

Comment: Is there a way to pass back a list of textview elements to an adapter?

Comment: try now the updated code to check shuffling issue solved or not.

Comment: another possible way to achieve your requirement (changing backgrouond color) is by using custom adapter.

Comment: did you call setContentView() before initializing gridview?

Comment: I actually had a small error causing the function to not work, however it still somehow only shuffles the TextView text and not their associated colors and attributes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98401/discussion-between-sachins-and-cameron-sima).